# C++ macro functions with "..." parameter

Tags: c++, macros, variadic-macros

What does "..." parameter in macro function mean and what does it do?

```
#define ABC(...) some Code Here
```

I don't understand what does this "..." in parameter help with and when should I use them?
I have tried goggling about it but all i get is info on what are macros, macro functions, parametrized macro functions etc.

Comment: Ew, macros. You should avoid them, they are simply bad. `...` in C means variadric function; perhaps it's the same in the preprocessor?

Answer (score 0):

The `...` is for [variadic macro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_macro) and it is generally used with `__VA_ARGS__` which is its expansion.